# Cannot open DLLs with Dependency Walker in Windows 8

Tags: windows-8

When trying to open a DLL file with [Dependency Walker](http://www.dependencywalker.com/) to see exported symbols and other stuff via **Open With** / **Look for another app on this PC** I'm getting an unhelpful error box saying:

> The program you have selected cannot be associated with this file
>   type. Please choose another application.

What can I do about this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found a solution here: http://answers.microsoft.com/pl-pl/windows/forum/windows_8-files/program-you-have-selected-cannot-be-associated/a1721936-2c6b-4a51-b773-ec351822c374?tab=AllReplies#tabs

There was a registry key at `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Applications\depends.exe` called `NoOpenWith`, after deleting I've been able to open DLLs with Dependency Walker.